# How to calculate total runs for given data in python

Tags: python-3.7

I have a dataset of IPL matches with few attributes. I am supposed to compute new attribute values (Total Runs) in Python using the attributes given in the dataset (Runs).

In the dataset, runs with respect to each ball is given (attribute name - Runs). example: for the 1st ball run scored is 1, run scored for 2nd ball is 0, run scored for 3rd ball is 4 and so on... I am supposed to calculate total runs i.e, total runs for 1st ball is 1, total runs for 2nd ball is 1, total runs for 3rd ball is 5...

I have tried writing code in python to compute total runs for each ball but I am getting few errors in Anaconda prompt:

> File "C:\Users\admin\First_Inning.py", line 1
>       MatchId        Inning        BattingTeam        BowlingTeam        Overs        Ball        Batsman        NonStriker        Bowler        IsSuperOver        WideRuns        ByeRuns        LegByeRuns        NoBallRuns        PenaltyRuns        BatsmanRuns        ExtraRuns        Runs        PlayerDismissed        DismissalKind        Fielder        TotalRuns        CRR        RRR        PreviousRuns        BatsmanSR        BowlerAvg        Wickets
>                           ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
#Python Code
#Dataset name - First_Inning
#TotalRuns is the attribute to which value as to be computed
#Runs - attribute in the given dataset i.e, runs with respect to each ball using which total runs as to be calculated

import First_Inning.py #Dataset name - First_Inning

x = 0
with open(r'C:\Users\admin\First_Inning.py', 'a') as f:
     def Total_Runs(x,TotalRuns):
        for line in f.readlines():
            TotalRuns = x, x = Runs + x 
            return TotalRuns

f.write(TotalRuns)
f.close
```

### Expected Results

```
Ball      1 2 3
Runs      1 0 4
TotalRuns 1 1 5
```

> Actual Result:
>   File "C:\Users\admin\First_Inning.py", line 1
>       MatchId        Inning        BattingTeam        BowlingTeam        Overs        Ball        Batsman        NonStriker        Bowler        IsSuperOver        WideRuns        ByeRuns        LegByeRuns        NoBallRuns        PenaltyRuns        BatsmanRuns        ExtraRuns        Runs        PlayerDismissed        DismissalKind        Fielder        TotalRuns        CRR        RRR        PreviousRuns        BatsmanSR        BowlerAvg        Wickets
>                           ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

[Deliveries.csv](https://data.world/vijayabhaskar/ipl-all-match-complete-data#)

Comment: what does your First_Inning.py file look like? This is the source of your error

Comment: It as 21 attributes namely - MatchId, Inning, BattingTeam, BowlingTeam,     Overs, Ball, Batsman, NonStriker, Bowler, IsSuperOver, WideRuns,       ByeRuns, LegByeRuns, NoBallRuns, PenaltyRuns, BatsmanRuns,        ExtraRuns, Runs, PlayerDismissed, DismissalKind & Fielder. It has data of 577 matches with 1154 Innings. I have seperated 1st Innings to one file and 2nd Innings to another file (First_Inning.py & Second_Inning.py). I have downloaded the dataset from dataworld.com and the name of the dataset downloaded is deliveries.csv. Kindly help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please add both of the files you're reading the contents from into your question

Comment: I have added the original dataset into the question (Deliveries.csv). Further I have seperated Innings = 1 into First_Inning.py & Innings = 2 into Second_Inning.py. Also I have added extra field names - TotalRuns, CRR, RRR, PreviousRuns, BatsmanSR, BowlerAvg and Wickets. Now I am supposed to compute values to these newly added fields. Kindly check it out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't have access to the dataset, but the way you're trying to read in your file is incorrect: C:\Users\admin\First_Inning.py should be a .csv extension not a python extension

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting the same error even after making the corrections that you have suggested.

Comment: I suspect it is a character issue, may want to see what line and column number it's complaining on

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out